# MacOSX Promised files drag&drop howto?

Tags: macos, drag-and-drop

It's not clear to me how to do drag&drop to Finder with

`dragPromisedFilesOfTypes:fromRect:source:slideBack:event: (NSCollectionView)`

I call the above method from mouseDown:, but

```
(NSArray *)namesOfPromisedFilesDroppedAtDestination:(NSURL *)dropDestination
```

isn't called at all.

Any ideas how this should work (MacOSX 10.6, project compiled for 10.5, 64bit)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had missed one method implementation: `(NSDragOperation)draggingSourceOperationMaskForLocal:(BOOL)isLocal`. This solved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Have you already looked at the Drag and Drop Programming Topics?  This whole book is on drag & drop, and it has a section specifically on file promises.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/Tasks/DraggingFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001288-102943

Comment: Yes, I've read the whole topic (and everything that's drag&drop in documentation. The issue is, that I don't get the namesOfPromisedFilesDroppedAtDestination:(NSURL *)dropDestination method called in my dragging source.

Comment: That's very strange... Sorry I couldn't be more help troubleshooting -- I haven't really done much work in this area.  Looks like you've found a solution though.

Comment: That documentation is really uncleer- it just says assume that droplocation exists but doesn't say where it comes from.

Comment: @MobileBloke It's not you, but the destination, that determines the "dropDestination", so if the user drags from your app to the Finder Desktop and releases the mouse button there, you'll get a dropDestination of "~/Desktop". Having said that, the Apple documentation is indeed a sad joke. Some of the AppKit methods aren't just deprecated, but officially obsolete. Good luck!